# Linked List cursor won't go to the next node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to create a Linked List in C, and I can't seem to figure out why my cursor won't go to the next node. I'm setting the current node to the next node, yet when I print out the cursor address, it's the same. I believe this is causing my to have a infinite loop, since that's my main problem. I'm setting the next pointer with:

```
orig_cursor = orig_cursor->next;
```

My entire method is below:

```
struct node* copyList()
{
    if(!head)
        return NULL;

    struct node *head_copy = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *copy_cursor = head_copy;
    struct node *orig_cursor = head;

    head_copy->data = head->data;
    head_copy->next = NULL;

    if(orig_cursor->next)
    {
        while(orig_cursor)
        {
            copy_cursor->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            copy_cursor = copy_cursor->next;

            printf("Original cursor pre-traversal = %d\n", orig_cursor->next);
            orig_cursor = orig_cursor->next;
            printf("Original cursor post-traversal = %d\n", orig_cursor->next);

            copy_cursor->data = orig_cursor->data;

            if(!orig_cursor->next)
            {
                copy_cursor->next = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return head_copy;
}
```

I also use the following push() function to push nodes into the list:

```
void push(int data)
{
    if(!head)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }

    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Pointers should be printed with `%p` not `%d`. Most likely you are running a 64 bit binary and your pointer value output is truncated due to the incorrect format specifier. So that it prints only the top 32 bits which is likely to be the same for both pointers. Alternatively you have a loop in your list :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about %p. However, my problem is that I'm stuck in an infinite loop in this list and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Also, I just tested the method with %p instead, and the pointer values are exactly the same.

Comment: In that case you need to show how the list was constructed. By the time you get here the problem is already in place. Also, this: `copy_cursor = copy_cursor->next;` is wrong. You just malloced `copy_cursor` so the `next` field contains garbage.

Comment: The list is created with a push() method that I created. And wouldn't using copy_cursor = copy_cursor->next just be setting cursor to the memory that I allocated? Which I then set the data of. This also doesn't explain why orig_cursor isn't traversing.

Comment: Ok, but you need to show the `push` function and how it is called. Because it appears the list is incorrectly constructed. Showing the use of an incorrectly constructed list doesn't tell us why/how that incorrect list came to be. In fact, you really need to provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise it'll just be this to and fro asking for all the relevant info.

Comment: I have updated my post with the push function that I am using. I'm not sure how else to create an example out of this..?

Comment: @Kyler Brown - You already have a Complete and Verifiable Example - the program that you ran and found to misbehave. You might post that program, or try to minimize it by removing unnecessary parts while retaining the problematic behavior - but don't take the "Minimal" too serious.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
struct node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: Casting the return of `malloc` is unnecessary because void pointers are implicitly converted, in fact, it's bad because it may hide the fact that one forgot to include `stdlib.h`.